# A Hashset that holds a generic linked list that holds a generic linked list

Tags: c, generics, hash, linked-list, void-pointers

This is my data structure for an Assignment I'm doing in class. I'm supposed to implement a a hash set that holds a string of linked lists. Each of those individual linked lists holds an int. My list is generic, if it works, using (void* data) like this:

```
 typedef struct NodeStruct {
     void *data;
     struct NodeStruct* next;
     struct NodeStruct* prev;
 } NodeStruct;

 //  Rename NodeStruct* as NodePtr
 typedef NodeStruct* NodePtr;

 typedef struct ListStruct {
     int elementType;
     NodePtr first;
     NodePtr last;
     NodePtr current;
 } ListStruct;

 //  ListHndl is just a ListStruct* renamed.
```

**First question**: Right now, I"m using `memcpy(list->data, data, list->elementType)`.
I was wondering.. is it okay do just store it directly, like `list->data = data`?

This is my hash set struct:

```
 typedef struct HashStruct {
     int size;
     int load;
     ListHndl *chain; //An array of Linked Lists.
 } HashStruct;

typedef HashStruct* HashHandle

 HashHandle new_hashset(int size) {
     HashHandle tempHash = malloc (sizeof (HashStruct));
     assert (tempHash != NULL);
     tempHash->size = size;
     tempHash->load = 0;
     tempHash->chain = malloc (sizeof (ListHndl) * size);
     assert(tempHash->chain != NULL);
     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
         tempHash->chain[i] = newList(sizeof(char*));
         tempHash->chain[i]->data = malloc(sizeof (ListHndl)); // Error here
     }
     return tempHash;
 }
```

This is the error that I'm getting.

```
hash.c: In function ‘new_hashset’:
hash.c:28:27: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
         tempHash->chain[i]->data = malloc(sizeof (ListHndl));
                           ^
```

**Second question:** I'm not sure how I'm supposed to be allocating memory for these linked lists, which is probably why I got this error.

Am I even implementing this data structure correctly? If more information is needed, please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: [stylistic hint] Get rid of the typedefs; their only purpose is to confuse you.

Answer (score 0):

`First question: Right now, I"m using memcpy(list->data, data, list->elementType).  I was wondering.. is it okay do just store it directly, like list->data = data?`

That depends on what 'data' is pointing to. It is quite common to `list->data = data` when 'data' is pointing to memory allocated from the heap,

---

`Second question: I'm not sure how I'm supposed to be allocating memory for these linked lists, which is probably why I got this error.`

For the typedefs outlined in the question, you will need to allocate memory for:

- Each new node: `newNode=malloc(sizeof(NodeStruct))`
- Each node payload: `newNode->data = malloc(sizeof(int))`

---

`Am I even implementing this data structure correctly?`

It is difficult to say with the limited code provided.  Of course, there are many ways to accomplish the assigned task; including those ways that are easier to understand, as well as those which are specifically tuned for performance.